# compile SML in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, sml

I have downloaded NPPexec and i use this command to execute SML in my notepad++. It works, the problem is that the process is kinda still running. So next time I press F6, I have to terminate it, before I can run it again. Is there a way of undoing this, so that "script" below will end the process for me?

```
NPP_SAVE
cd "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
C:\Program Files (x86)\mosml\bin\mosml.exe -c "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
quit()
```

Comment: You could try a workaround: create a second nppexec script which kills the progam, something like "taskkill /im mosml.exe /f" and bind it to a keyboard shortcut. Another possibility would be to include the taskkill in your nppexec script before you run mosml.